# Help!How can I boot Ubuntu without a USB or CD, but have no OS installed on a computer

Tags: boot, usb

I am building a budget PC and just want to use Ubuntu as a primary Operating System. I am new to using it and want to ask is there any way I can just put it directly onto the SSD and boot it from there. Is there any way around using a USB or CD in the computer to boot it each time? Do I have to install it through Windows?

Comment: No, there's no way around and no, you don't install it "from Windows" either. There are options like a network install but that obviously requires a server that you don't have. Also possible to boot an ISO from Grub and then install as usual but in order to do that you'd need some Linux with Grub already installed.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Thank you so much for the response!

Comment: You can plug your SSD into a friends computer and install Ubuntu to it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can plug your SSD into a friends computer and install Ubuntu to it from there.

You will need the Ubuntu ISO, (or other image). You can install directly from your friends computer without USB, CD or network if they have VirtualBox installed.

See my answer here > [Full install of Ubuntu on a USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857605/full-install-of-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive/857868#857868) (substitute SSD for USB)

Do not install any proprietary drivers until you move the SSD back to your machine.

This method works in both Linux and Windows machines